# Rudin Ex. 7.22: if $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ there are polynomials $P_n$ s.t. $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^b_a\left|f-P_n\right|^2\,d\alpha=0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

The problem

> Assume $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, and prove that there are polynomials $P_n$ such that
> $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^b_a\left|f-P_n\right|^2\,d\alpha=0\mbox{.} $$

Some results from the book I shall use.

> **Ex 6.12** Suppose $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that there exists a continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that $\left\{\int^b_a\left|f-g\right|^2\,d\alpha\right\}^{1/2}<\epsilon$.

> **Ex 7.2** If $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ converge uniformly on a set $E$, prove that $\{f_n+g_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E$. If, in addition, $\{f_n\},\{g_n\}$ are sequences of bounded functions, prove that $\{f_ng_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E$.

> **Thm 7.26** If $f$ is a continuous real function on $[a,b]$, there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that
> $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_n(x)=f(x) $$
> uniformly on $[a,b]$.

*Proof of the problem.* By Ex 6.12, for each positive integer $n$, we can find a continuous function $g_n$ on $[a,b]$ such that
$$ \int^b_a\left|f-g_n\right|^2\,d\alpha<\frac{1}{n}\mbox{.} $$
By Thm 7.26, there is a sequence $\{P^{(n)}_k\}$ of polynomials converging uniformly to $g_n$. By Ex 7.2,
$$ \lvert f-P^{(n)}_k\rvert^2\rightarrow\lvert f-g_n\rvert^2\quad\mbox{uniformly}$$
as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, there exists an integer $K(n)$ such that
$$ \left|\int^b_a\lvert f-P^{(n)}_k\rvert^2\,d\alpha-\int^b_a\lvert f-g_n\rvert^2\,d\alpha\right|<\frac{1}{n} $$
provided only that $k\geq K(n)$; hence
$$ \int^b_a\lvert f-P^{(n)}_{K(n)}\rvert^2\,d\alpha<\frac{2}{n} \mbox{.} $$
Define a sequence $\{P_n\}$ of polynomials by $P_n=P^{(n)}_{K(n)}$. It is clear from the last inequality that
$$ \int^b_a\left|f-P_n\right|^2\,d\alpha\rightarrow0 \mbox{.} $$
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Does this look correct?

Comment: I would write $|f-P_k^{(n)}| \le |f-g_n| + |g_n-P_k^{(n)}|$ and conclude directly.

Comment: @copper.hat How do you deal with square?

Comment: Oops, I missed the square. Are you familiar with the Minkowski inequality?